# volume under (graph of a) function

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have a unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and some function $f(x,y)$. Say you want to find the volume below the the plane $y=x$. Would it be

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1} f(x,y) \ dx \ dy$$?

Comment: In $3$D (i.e. $xyz$), $y=x$ is not a line. It's a plane.

Comment: And it's a vertical plane, so it's not clear what's meant by "below".

Comment: James, a plane will divide the 3D space into two sides. It is not hard to visualize/draw in 3D. Which side do you think about?

Comment: @J.D.: All I mean is the region for which $y<x$ in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. I am correct right?

Comment: Yes, the region described in your last comment would give the integral in your post.

Comment: Actually, I was guessing what you wanted in the previous comment. If $f(x,y)\ge 0$ and if $R$ is the region in the $x$-$y$ plane for which  $(x,y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $y<x$, then the volume of the solid bounded above by the graph of $f$ and below by $R$ is the integral in your post.